# Bold a single line in table using php

Tags: php, html

```
|          |   Major Heading 1    |  Major Heading 2    |
| Minor1   |   Minor2  |  Minor3  | Minor4  |  Minor5   |
|          ----------------------------------------------
| col1     |   col2    |   col3   |   col4  |    col5   |
```

That above is how my table looks like. Now the words in col2 & col3
 are the same with col4 & 5. therefore i need the line between col3 & 4
 to be bold.

```
echo "<table border='1' id = 'frmnew' cellpadding='10'>";

echo "<tr>
    <th rowspan='2'><center><b>Part Number</b></center></th>
    <th rowspan='2'><center><b>Minimum Quantity</b></center></th>
    <th rowspan='2'><center><b>Maximum Quantity</b></center></th>

    <th colspan='4' scope='colgroup'><center>SHIP AGAINST PO</center></th>
    <th colspan='4' scope='colgroup'><center>FORECAST FROM VARIOUS REGIONS PENDING FOR INTERCO PO</center></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope='col'><center>UK</center></th>
    <th scope='col'><center>US</center></th>
    <th scope='col'><center>ASIA</center></th>
    <th scope='col'><center>MEXICO</center></th>
    <th scope='col'><center>UK</center></th>
    <th scope='col'><center>US</center></th>
    <th scope='col'><center>ASIA</center></th>
    <th scope='col'><center>MEXICO</center></th>
  </tr>";
```

Those are the codes. The same line will be confusing. Also, i need the line to be bold from the top to the end of the table. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you explain what the question is because it is not clear at all

Comment: @RamRaider I want to bold the border line between col3 and col 4. But i don't know how to do it unless bolding all the lines

Comment: you could assign a class to `td` in col 3 and use `border-right:2px solid black` in css

Comment: @syerarasyad check my answer, i edited it. in case you are the one who downvoted it because you didn't see the answer beacuse i didn't write the code properly and you didn't see it, just check it now and upvote it please

Comment: @OrangeOrange omg that wasn't me

Comment: @syerarasyad ok, is it working?

Comment: @OrangeOrange No because the table i'm doing is a table where the user can edit and delete the datas to be stored into the database. I don't want to open the hardcode every time the user enter a new data. Don't you agree with me?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
echo "<table border='1' id = 'frmnew' cellpadding='10'>";

echo "<tr>
    <th rowspan='2'><center><b>Part Number</b></center></th>
    <th rowspan='2'><center><b>Minimum Quantity</b></center></th>
    <th rowspan='2'><center><b>Maximum Quantity</b></center></th>

    <th colspan='4' scope='colgroup' style='border-right:none;'><center>SHIP AGAINST PO</center></th>
    <th colspan='4' scope='colgroup' style='border-left: 5px solid black;'><center>FORECAST FROM VARIOUS REGIONS PENDING FOR INTERCO PO</center></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope='col'><center>UK</center></th>
    <th scope='col'><center>US</center></th>
    <th scope='col'><center>ASIA</center></th>
    <th scope='col' style='border-right:none;'><center>MEXICO</center></th>
    <th scope='col' style='border-left: 5px solid black;'><center>UK</center></th>
    <th scope='col'><center>US</center></th>
    <th scope='col'><center>ASIA</center></th>
    <th scope='col'><center>MEXICO</center></th>
  </tr>";

  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I need the line to be bold from top to bottom. Sorry for the unclear question

Comment: It works only for the two row. If i enter a data into the table by using UI/UX, i have to edit the hardcode to put the style. So, no

Comment: Are you looping <th> ?

Comment: No i am not looping the <th>

Answer (score 0):

To bold certain *lines* in your table you could add border styles for each **column**.

Adding `border-right-style: solid;` to your column 3 should possibly do the trick

You can of course also do this for column 4 where you would say `border-left-style: solid;`

It's adviced to set the right border to none if you want to add a border to left and the other way around ofcourse `border-right-style: none`

Comment: I need the line to be bold from top to bottom. Sorry for the unclear question

Comment: @syerarasyad are you looping the table? If so you could add it in the loop so that it would add it to every <tr> created

Comment: No unfortunately no :(

Comment: An other solution would be to make 2 tables in 1 table, which is nesting multiple tables basically. If you do this you can seperate them by adding a margin between them and styling both tables as you like. This might be a good solution for your problem

Comment: @syerarasyad ^^^^

Comment: How to actually have 2 tables in 1? I mean, will it display both tables or i have to set the visibility hidden?

Comment: @syerarasyad look at this page: it explains it quite well, if you do not understand this i can give you an fiddle to explain it to you. http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/tables/nestingtables.html

Comment: Alright i understand about the nesting table. About a table in another table. However, i can't see how it'll help me :( Sorry

Comment: @syerarasyad i will make you a small example wait a few minutes

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll be waiting

Comment: @syerarasyad I have been fiddling thinking about your problem, and I think 2 tables inline would be an better solution, since nesting the tables has no more extra value in this situation: http://jsfiddle.net/SM769/